# Fn+F2 is not working to rename a file

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is used as shortcut to rename a file. But this is not working for me. Probably I changed some keymap or configuration somewhere. How can I make this work again? How can I set <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> as file rename shortcut?

Comment: Can you provide some more information in general, if not specific, as to how you may have "changed some keymap" settings? Were you deliberately attempting to change keymaps? If so, how were you going about it?

Comment: On some laptops, you can change whether the Fn key is needed or not. Try F2 without Fn to see if you can rename that way. If that works, the meaning of Fn has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible that you're just misremembering the correct shortcut.

To rename a file in Nautilus, simply select the file and press <kbd>**F2**</kbd> (*without* pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key).

Comment: some laptops put media keys on the `F1-FX` keys (you press `Fn-F1` for volume-up, `Fn-F2` for volume-down, etc).  a common trick is to then reverse that (in firmware) so `F1` gets volume-up and you have to press `Fn-F1` for the OS to see `F1`.  sometimes there's a firmware/BIOS setting to control which way the keys default, sometimes not.  (i think some systems can be software controlled, via kernel driver parameter or XKB.  heavily hardware dependent.)  perhaps this user's setting has changed recently.

Comment: But in my lenovo laptop F1, F2, F3 used for volume mute, up and down. And fn+F2 was the shortcut for renaming.  Anyway, F2 or fn+F2 none of them works as renaming shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in my CentOS, where pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> causes the Gno-menu dropdown to pop up. But when I toggle it off in the extensions manager the shortcut for renaming starts working again.

You might want to turn off any such extensions which you might have which have other functions assigned to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.