# F2 is like a right-click instead of "rename"

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dolphin, konqueror

Until recently, when I pressed F2 in Konqueror/Dolphin, I got to rename a file or folder. But now the little action window appears in which I can select stuff like "Open in new window" and so on - the little window which should only open when I right click on a file or folder. How can I go back to the old behavior? I tried to use "Settings -> Set Keyboard Shortcuts" but there, F2 is only linked to renaming. I am not sure what interferes.

---

Btw, [Fn+F2 is not working to rename a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908522/fnf2-is-not-working-to-rename-a-file) did not provide anything to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it had nothing to do with Software. My Logitech Keyboard does not use the F-keys as F-keys by default, but the other meanings (e.g. turn music louder). After I changed batteries in my keyboard this default behavior was reactivated. To turns this "feature" off, one needs to press "fn"+"Esc".

For German speaking people: https://www.tutonaut.de/logitech-f-tasten-auf-tastaturen-aktivieren/